# reformat callback value to add a space between each value

Tags: jquery

I have two requests.. I would like to experiment with both solutions and see which looks better.

1. I would like to reformat the api callback string to add a space
   after each domain, the seperator is `,`
2. I would like a separate solution to reformat the same string to show all the domain names in list form.

I am making a call to api and the callback string is:

> endpoint1.details.cert.altNames

The value of the above is:

```
www.domain.com,domain.net,ftp.hostname.org.au
```

**For the first solution** I basically want to reformat the value output so it has a space between each domain name i.e. `www.domain.com, domain.net, ftp.hostname.org.au`

**For the second solution** I would like to reformat the same string so it is displayed in list form

- www.domain.com
- domain.net
- ftp.hostname.org.au

Comment: You forgot to include the code that does what you want.

Comment: Why don't you split the string with `.split(',')`, which will produce an array of domain names? You can then manipulate that array to do anything you want: by joining them with a space `.join(' ')`, joining them with a comma and space `.join(', ')`, or output them in a list using `.each()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.replace()` to replace `,` with `,` (with a trailing space).

```js
var input = "www.domain.com,domain.net,ftp.hostname.org.au";

input = input.replace(/,/g, ", ");

console.log(input);
```

*Learn:* [`String.prototype.replace()` - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

---

For your other solution, use `document.createElement` appropriately.

```js
//var input = '"www.geotrust.net", "geotrust.com", "www.geotrust.com"';

var inputArray = ["www.geotrust.net", "geotrust.com", "www.geotrust.com"];

console.dir(inputArray);

var list = makeUL(inputArray);

console.dir(list);

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(list);

function makeUL(array) {
    // Create the list element:
    var list = document.createElement('ol');

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Create the list item:
        var item = document.createElement('li');

        // Set its contents:
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));

        // Add it to the list:
        list.appendChild(item);
    }

    // Finally, return the constructed list:
    return list;
}
```

*Learn:* [`Document.createElement()` - Web API Interfaces | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Comment: your example works but when i use my string it doesnt.. here is the output of my string _endpoint1.details.cert.altNames_ `"www.geotrust.net", "geotrust.com", "www.geotrust.com"`

Comment: thats odd.. i just noticed my api call back string does actually have spaces in the console.log but when i output with jquery there is no spaces.. any ideas?

Comment: @user3436467 In response to your first comment, checkout the second updated code snippet.

Comment: @user3436467 How did you output it with jQuery?

Comment: set.append('<div><b>SANs:</b> '+endpoint1.details.cert.altNames+'</div>');

Comment: @user3436467 I believe that works. http://jsfiddle.net/gwvq6yhp/ Any error in the console?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75084/discussion-between-rahul-desai-and-user3436467).

Comment: thank you for your kind and professional assistance. I am all set now:)

Comment: @user3436467 I am glad it helped. Make sure that you learn from my code. It shouldnt be a simple copy-paste. ;)